# Unexpected token "}" error with LiteralControl

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a dynamic table with users from my asp.net app (using membership class).
I'm trying to add a  control inside each role cell in order to open a popup using javascript. Right now I only check to see if the function fires up. but when I click the cell an error occurs: **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"**.

**here is my aspx:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function alert_function(id)
       {
        alert(id);
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:placeholder ID="Placeholder1" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>

    </div>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**and my code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

        Table tbl = new Table();

        TableRow h_row = new TableRow();
        TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
        TableCell c3 = new TableCell();
        TableCell c4 = new TableCell();
        TableCell c5 = new TableCell();
        TableCell c6 = new TableCell();

        c1.Text = "משתמש מחובר?";
        c2.Text = "התחבר לאחרונה";
        c3.Text = "נוצר ב";
        c4.Text = "דואר אלקטרוני";
        c5.Text = "תפקיד";
        c6.Text = "שם משתמש";

        h_row.Controls.Add(c1);
        h_row.Controls.Add(c2);
        h_row.Controls.Add(c3);
        h_row.Controls.Add(c4);
        h_row.Controls.Add(c5);
        h_row.Controls.Add(c6);

        tbl.Controls.Add(h_row);


        foreach (MembershipUser u in users)
        {
            TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cell6 = new TableCell();

            cell1.Text = u.IsOnline.ToString();
            cell2.Text = u.LastLoginDate.ToString();
            cell3.Text = u.CreationDate.ToString();
            cell4.Text = u.Email;
            string user_name=u.UserName;
            string[] role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user_name);
            if (role.Length < 1)
                cell5.Text = "אין תפקיד";
            **else
            {
                LiteralControl lc=new LiteralControl("<a onclick='alert_function('"+u.UserName.ToString()+"')'>" + role[0] + "</a>");
                cell5.Controls.Add(lc);
            }**

            cell6.Text = u.UserName;

            row1.Controls.Add(cell1);
            row1.Controls.Add(cell2);
            row1.Controls.Add(cell3);
            row1.Controls.Add(cell4);
            row1.Controls.Add(cell5);
            row1.Controls.Add(cell6);

            tbl.Controls.Add(row1);
        }

        Placeholder1.Controls.Add(tbl);

    }
```

**It's weird, because when I change the hilighted line in the code to:

```
LiteralControl lc=new LiteralControl("<a onclick='alert_function("+u.UserName.ToString()+")'>" + role[0] + "</a>");
```

(removing the "' '") It works, but the username won't send as a string so only numbers are being alerted.**

Comment: If you're using a string, it needs to be quoted. Numbers don't need to be quoted. Otherwise, JavaScript interprets it as a reference to a variable...which probably isn't defined

Comment: but it is quoted.. this error is weird..

Comment: You need to look at the source that actually ends up on in the browser. From that it will be much, much easier to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the quotes in your literal.

```
LiteralControl lc = 
    new LiteralControl("<a onclick='alert_function(\""
        + u.UserName.ToString() + "\")'>" + role[0] + "</a>");
```

or

```
LiteralControl lc = 
    new LiteralControl("<a onclick=\"alert_function('"
        +u.UserName.ToString()+"')\">" + role[0] + "</a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl(String.Format("<a 
   onclick=\"alert_function('{0}')\">{1}</a>", u.UserName.ToString(), role[0]));
```

Or

```
string link = String.Format("<a onclick=\"alert_function('{0}')\">{1}</a>", 
    u.UserName.ToString(), role[0]);
LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like you are using a single quote around onclick='alert_function('.  I understand you wrapped the entire thing in double quotes, so you try to avoid using double quotes within the alert_function('username') but that is incorrect.  Take, for instance, if you were to remove the outer quotes and look at the result as a string, you get onclick='alert_function('username')'.  Notice that your wrapped the onclick value in single quotes, but you are also using single quotes two wrap the username, if you look at this string alone you should be able to see the problem, the entire string should be wrapped in single quotes but instead you have multiple single quotes in there breaking the string into multiple strings.  You still need to alternate your single and double quotes so this does not happen, even when dealing with strings inside of strings.

To fix this, in places where you want to nest single or double quotes within a string that is already surrounded by that same quote, use the backslash escape.  This will literally put that quote character into the string as a character instead of ending the string.

```
LiteralControl lc=new LiteralControl("<a onclick='alert_function(\""+u.UserName.ToString()+"\")'>" + role[0] + "</a>");
```

This is basically your second solution, except I added a second \" to surround the value of your username in quotes within the string.